# how to use keyListener in java

Tags: java, keyboard-events

every one i want to display a message dialog on pressing of enter key in keyboard or clicking button on frame below is my code it work for clicking but not for key press please help me to do this working. Thanks in advance

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class Key extends JFrame implements ActionListener,KeyListener
{
    JTextField t1;
    JButton b1;
    Key()
    { 
       Container c=getContentPane();
       c.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
       t1=new JTextField();
       b1=new JButton("Click");
       c.add(t1);
       c.add(b1);
       setVisible(true);
       setSize(200,200);
       b1.addActionListener(this);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
   }
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
   {
       if(ae.getSource()==b1)
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Message:"+t1.getText());
   }
   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke)
   {
   }
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
   {
      int key = e.getKeyCode();

      if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Message:"+t1.getText());
       }
    }
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke)
   {
   }
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
    new Key();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never add the KeyListener. But actually it's better to use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to process ENTER.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Enter Key and Button](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/25/enter-key-and-button/). It explores a few ideas:

1. making the button the default button for the frame/dialog
2. dynamically changing the default button as a button gains focus
3. manually adding your own Key Bindings